# Can learning apocrypha count as Talmud Torah?

Tags: torah-study, apocrypha

According to [this post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83425/is-it-permissible-to-read-works-of-the-apocrypha), the apocrypha may be permissible to learn. Would learning it count as Talmud Torah?

Answer (score 3):

No.  Doesn't "learning Torah" mean learning from specific holy books (and commentaries based on them), and *not* from other books?  Would that not specifically exclude books that were considered for inclusion by the Sanhedrin and rejected?  If not, what *does* it mean?

Comment: So you wouldn't consider learning mussar Talmud Torah? Its not holy books, and if that is considered commentary on it, then why wouldn't the apocrypha?

Comment: I thought Mussar was rooted in Torah and halacha, concentrating on expounding on the ethical commandments of Judaism.

Comment: The Apocrypha were specifically examined and rejected.  How can anybody consider them Talmud Torah?

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Ahron Lopiansky once told one of his talmidim that the only reason (or manner in which) they can learn apocrypha is if they understand that it is ***not*** Torah. One can reasonably infer from that: otherwise, it is completely forbidden and you are putting your olam haba on the line.